# Implications of $\mathbb{E}(\max\{0,X\})=\infty$

Tags: integration, expected-value

Consider a continuous random variable $X$ such that
$$
\mathbb{E}(\max\{0,X\})=\infty
$$
Does this imply that
$$
|\mathbb{E}(X)|=\infty\quad \text{and/or} \quad \mathbb{E}(|X|)=\infty \quad ?
$$

- I believe the second holds because $\infty=\mathbb{E}(\max\{0,X\})\leq \mathbb{E}(|X|)$
- In turn, the first holds because $X$ is integrable if and only if $|X|$ is integrable

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It implies $\mathbb{E}|X|= \infty$ and it implies that $\mathbb{E}X$ is either $+ \infty$ or not defineable at all (that is if the positive and the negative part of $X$ have both infinite expactation, i.e. $X$ is not quasi-integrable)

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean "$|\mathbb{E} X|$ is either $+\infty$" (with the absolute value)?

Comment: No. If the positive and the negative part of $X$ have both infinite expactation, $\mathbb{E}X$ doesn't make sense. And the question is not only, if it sould be $+ \infty$ or $-\infty$, where you could argue that the asulte values cancles this out.